# Nvidia Shield OTA Updates and Rerooting

Tags: updates, unrooting, nvidia-shield

I own an Nvidia Shield tablet, and Nvidia has released an update to Android 5.1. I have a rooted device and may upgrade soon. So I have some questions:

1. Will I be able to install this while rooted?
2. If I tried, could it brick my device?
3. If I installed it would it unroot me?
4. If so how would I re-root? I rooted by unlocking the bootloader and installing CWM by the instructions at [here](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-root-nvidia-shield-tablet-android-5-0-lollipop-install-cwm-recovery-1481041).
5. I unlocked the boot-loader, if I re-root, would it erase my data or brick my device?

Answer (score 1):

Probably Not.

Android updates before Lollipop checked each system file and replaced them but after Lollipop, the updates check the whole system block as a part and update it. Since rooting modifies the system files, the System Block won't match and the update will abort.
Since you have a custom recovery, the update won't even go that far because you need Stock Recovery to install it.

TL;DR: Attempting to update won't brick your device; but why leave it to chance?
On the off chance you install stock recovery and proceed with the update and it works, yes, you would loose root. You can reroot the same way you did it before.